# Jquery-Ui dialog only working locally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, localhost, locale, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to Jquery and am running into a Problem. The Jquery code that I write only works Locally, as soon as i upload it to my host(godaddy.com) it stops working. Right now the website isn't really functional because i wanted too simplyfy the problem. I'm using google API to retrieve the Jquery library. When i use the `$` sign shortcut instead of "Jquery." The function that opens the dialog box(dia) runs but skips over the part the should open the dialog. When i use the Jquery object the function is skipped over completely and as far as i can tell from the errors, the function no longer exists from the browsers point of view. The website I'm working on is kind of an experiment, you can find it at [www.mgeffects.com](http://www.mgeffects.com). When you click on the `I'm  in a dialog` div tag it should popup the dialog as well as an alert i put in place as part of the debugging process, instead it does nothing. Right now its using "JQuery" instead of the `$` sign.

Thanks for any help i get.(by the way ignore the PHP errors you get in the black div tag.)

Comment: what happens if you replace `jQuery.(document).ready(function() {' by `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing your selectors wrong:

this is not a valid use:

```
// The dot after jQuery shouldn't be there
jQuery.("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

use this instead:

```
jQuery("#dialog").dialog('open');
//or
$("#dialog").dialog('open');
```

Also you are including jQuery twice:

```
//HERE
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<style type="text/css">
//AND HERE
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: @user918236 Also, same issue Chad mentioned with . (dot) in wrong place here: `jQuery.(document).ready(function()`. Should be `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Thanks so much, im new to stackoverflow so i might be typing this in the wrong place. I was taring my hair out trying to get this to work. When i look back at my work before i switched to the Jquery i found that i actually did do "$(foo)" but then did "jQuery.blah". I would have never figured out both bugs. Thanks again